# Create app-owned object using Facebook iOS SDK 3.5

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-opengraph

With the new Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 is possible to create app-owned & user-owned objects besides self-hosted objects.

For creating a user-owned object I can use this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object[@"type"] = @"books.book";
object[@"title"] = @"Snow Crash";
object[@"image"] = @"TODO";
object[@"url"] = @"https://example.com/book-app/books/Snow-Crash";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if(error) {
                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                   } else {
                                       NSLog(@"Success");
                                   }
                               }];
```

Does anyone knows what is needed to add or change to create an **app-owned object** instead of a user-owned object?

Comment: Thanks to a Facebook developer:

"There are no friendly helpers in the SDK to create app-owned objects. That is because app-owned objects require the app access token, which includes the app secret and should not be published to the client as part of the user's app. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#creatingapp for more info."

Answer (score 0):

For app-owned objects, you can use a curl operation:

`curl \
  -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/books.book"  \
  -F "access_token=$APP_TOKEN" \
  -F "object={
    \"title\":\"The Hunt for Red October\",
    \"image\":\"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/some_image.jpg\",
    \"url\":\"https://link.you.want.displayed/example/hunt-for-red-october-link\",
    \"description\":\"Classic cold war technothriller\",
    \"data\": {
      \"isbn\":\"425240339\"
    }
  }"`

Once you get the ID of the created object, just hard code it in your program. If you need more flexibility or have dynamic content, than app-owned objects are not the right choice.

For more details on the curl operation, checkout Facebook Docs on [App-Owned Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects).

To see the created object, visit [Object Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser), and make sure that the object owner is set to the name of your app from the drop-down menu, as such:

[image]